# Comparing EditText with string in C#

Tags: c#, android, string, xamarin, android-edittext

I'm new to C# and Android development (using Xamarin). I'm trying to create simple login screen that will check user input, and if user input matches with data in text files, it will show that login is successful, othervise it will show that login failed.

I have to mention that I'm struggling with this for almost a day. I thought I've messed something up in coding, so I created simple console application, copied code over there and it worked perfectly, so I assume that my problem is related to comparing string with user input from EditText.

App builds successfully, but every time i press button related to method which is shown below, my app crashes and throw me out.

I created two text files named user.txt and pass.txt. First line in pass.txt is password for user on the first line in user.txt.

Once again, I have to mention that code works perfectly in console application (I replaced user_input from EditText with simple Console.Readline and Toast.MakeText with Console.Writeline). Please, what am I doing wrong?

```
    public void read_list(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        k = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.user);
        z = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.pass);

        string user_input = k.Text.ToString();
        string pass_input = z.Text.ToString();

        int count = 0;
        bool valid = false;
        const string person = "user.txt";
        List<string> users = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader username = new StreamReader(person))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = username.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                users.Add(line);
            }

            foreach (string s in users)
            {
                if (Equals(s, user_input))
                {
                    valid = true;
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }

        }


        const string key = "pass.txt";
        List<string> passwords = new List<string>();
        bool pass_valid = false;

        using (StreamReader password = new StreamReader(key))
        {
            string pass_line;
            while ((pass_line = password.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                passwords.Add(pass_line);
            }

            if (Equals(passwords[count], pass_input))
            {
                pass_valid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pass_valid = false;
            }

        }

        if ((pass_valid) && (valid))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Login successful", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Login failed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: please show error logs if application is crashing

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : There are no error logs. App just crashes and says "Unfortunately, App stopped working" and throw me out. Not a single error in Visual Studio or something else.

Comment: I doubt that very much. Can you check the output page (View > Output in VS2013) and see if there are any exceptions listed there? Apps don't just crash without giving some indication that there is a problem... unless of course you suppressed all errors.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, you can also step through the code you suspect holds the problem in the debugger.

Comment: @matejcro Because your path of store .txt file isn't correct.

Comment: @VetaLio: I changed it to C:\\...\\user.txt (full path), but it's crashing again.

Comment: @matejcro so you want to check txt files from PC,via your application? How do you image this? Via usb-cable :D ? It's incorrect way,because very complicated(need to make client,write API and etc). So for you case, need to store this txt files(better to make 1 txt file,where is first rows is Account,second is password),localy(into flash memory of mobile phone) and then acces them to check if was introduced correct credentials.

Comment: @matejcro ill show you how to do this,but little bit later.

Comment: @VetaLio: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @matejcro check my answer!

Comment: @VetaLio: Thanks once again. It worked! :-)

Comment: @matejcro you're welcome ;). I also up voted your question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as i said,your main concept is wrong. Lets see my example,check this out:
**MainActivity** looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;

namespace TestStuff
{
    [Activity(Label = "Main",MainLauncher=true,Icon = "@drawable/icon")]            
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        //path of folder,where we want to save our .txt File(Downloads)
        Java.IO.File FolderToSave = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Second);

            EditText login = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText2);
            Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
            //here is final Path of our Credentials.txt
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderToSave.Path, "Credentials.txt");
            //method,that will write correct login/password to .txt file
            this.WriteFile("Vasya", "12345",filePath);
            //eventhandler,when we pressing the button,method "check credentials will do some stuff
            btn.Click += (sender, e) => 
                {
                  //put parametrs: location of Credentials.txt and    current login and password
  CheckForCredentials(filePath,login.Text,password.Text);
                    };

        }
        //create and write credentials.txt with login and pass
        void WriteFile(string Login,string Password,string Path)
        {
            using (StreamWriter Credentials = new StreamWriter (Path))
            {
                //first row will be our login
                Credentials.WriteLine(Login);
                //second is password
                Credentials.WriteLine(Password);
            }
        }

        //check for correct data
        void CheckForCredentials(string Path,string CurrentLogin,string CurrentPassword)
        {
            string Login, Password;
            if (File.Exists(Path))
            {
                //reading from Credentials.txt first rows(that is our login)
                Login = File.ReadLines(Path).First();
                //same for password
                Password = File.ReadLines(Path).Last();

                //check if introduced values are correct!
                if (Login == CurrentLogin && Password == CurrentPassword)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Credentials are correct", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Something going wrong", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //credentials for some reason doest exist in your app.
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Not exist file", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainLayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:hint="UserName" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:hint="Password" />
        <Button
            android:text="Check Credentials"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, you need to put permissions in your **AndroidManifest.xml**(Located in folder **Propreties**) this:

1. WriteExternalStorage
2. ReadExternalStorage

And that is all :).